# AngularJS disable 2 way binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This actually might be a JavaScript question, but it is happening when I am using AngularJs.

Say I have an array like this:

```
var players = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Player 1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Player 2'
    }
];
```

and then I have another array like this:

```
var teams = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Team 1',
        members: players
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Team 2',
        members: players
    }
];
```

If I decide to add a new property called position to one of the teams:

```
teams[0].members[0].position = 1;
```

I don't want it to then update the second team members position.
I hope that makes sense.

Here is a codepen to illustrate my issue:

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/ZGZXjb?editors=101

Comment: How come both teams have the same players?

Comment: That's always going to happen because `members` on both teams points to the same object!

Comment: Data doesn't make sense....you would never be storing the data this way where you have reference to same javascript object

Comment: Actually you have create the new object in 0'th index only. The result coming from your input. that's all.

Comment: It was an example that I put together, in my application it is a sports shopping cart and you assign a player / player number to the garment and then set the quantity of items per player per garment. But the example I posted was easier to explain :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array in java-script are mutable so you need to make copy of player and assign it to teams member property.

Just change your code to :

```
var teams = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Team 1',
    members: angular.copy(players)
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Team 2',
    members: angular.copy(players)
}
```

];

for more information see : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: I was hoping there was a better solution that having to loop through each player and create a new object for each one.

Comment: How can you achieve this when change the value on text box?

Comment: @ramesh you mean making copy of object binded to textbox as its model change?

Comment: Yes,  You need to use `scope.watch()`.

Answer (score 2):

The only way (if both teams have the same players) is to use a copy of the array for the second team. Now it's logical the second team gets updated, because both teams point to the same reference of `players`.

You can use [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) for that.

```
var copyofplayers = [];
angular.copy(players, copyofplayers);
```

Comment: Alternatively if using lodash, you can `_.cloneDeep(players)`

Answer (score 0):

also can use jQuery.extend() like

```
var teams = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Team 1',
    members: jQuery.extend({}, players)
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Team 2',
    members: jQuery.extend({}, players)
}
];
```

Comment: Yeah but I don't use jQuery with AngularJs